# ¿Hay una forma más simple de obtener el ID de un dato recién agregado en mi base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Me explico, actualmente estoy agregando datos a la DB, el problema que tengo es que cuando termino de agregar ese dato, necesito recuperar el ID que se generó automáticamente para poder actualizar otra tabla. Actualmente lo que hago es, después de generar el `INSERT`, hago otra consulta que detallo a continuación:

**INSERTO LA NUEVA INFORMACIÓN:**

```
$newChof = Conexion::Conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO Conductores(Nombre, ApellidoP, ApellidoM, imgPerfil, IDUnidad, IDEmpresa, IDTelefono) VALUES(:DT1, :DT2, :DT3, :DT4, :DT5, :DT6, :DT7)");
$newChof->bindParam(":DT1", $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$newChof->bindParam(":DT2", $ap, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$newChof->bindParam(":DT3", $am, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$newChof->bindParam(":DT4", $Empty, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$newChof->bindParam(":DT5", $Zero, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$newChof->bindParam(":DT6", $One, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$newChof->bindParam(":DT7", $phoneID["IDTelefono"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$newChof->execute();
```

**HAGO OTRA CONSULTA PARA OBTENER EL ÚLTIMO DATO INSERTADO:**

```
$getNewID = Conexion::Conectar()->prepare("SELECT IDConductor FROM Conductores ORDER BY IDConductor DESC LIMIT 1");
$getNewID->execute();
$conductorID = $getNewID->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**ACTUALIZO LA OTRA TLABA CON EL ID OBTENIDO RECIENTEMENTE:**

```
$updatePhoneID = Conexion::Conectar()->prepare("UPDATE Telefonos SET IDUsuario = :nuevoIDC WHERE IDTelefono = :idPhone");
$updatePhoneID->bindParam(":nuevoIDC", $choferID["IDConductor"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$updatePhoneID->bindParam(":idPhone", $phoneID["IDTelefono"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$updatePhoneID->execute();
```

**DEFINICION DE MIS TABLAS:**

Tabla de conductores:
[image: Esta es la tabla de conductores, y su ID o PK es <code>IDConductor</code>]

Tabla de teléfonos:
[image: Esta es la tabla donde almaceno los teléfonos y su ID o PK es <code>IDTelefonos</code>]

> Como aclaración, he estado leyendo que no es recomendable tener una tabla para guardar teléfonos como la tengo actualmente, y es una cosa que estoy pensando cambiar en un futuro no muy lejano, pero tengo esa curiosidad o intriga de si hay una forma mas eficiente de obtener el ID generado de un `INSERT` previo para no tener que hacer una nueva consulta, o hacer todo lo que requiero en una sola consulta.

Comment: Como esta definida la tabla? quien te dijo que no es recomendable tener una tabla de telefonos?? y si el usuario tuviera 3 telefonos donde los vas a guardar?

Comment: Actualice la pregunta con las tablas. En cuanto a lo de tener la tabla de teléfonos así en diversos foros he visto que muchos sugieren tener una tabla intermedia que conecte la de los conductores (en este caso) y la de los teléfonos.

Comment: En realidad, no es necesario.. si tu tabla telefono tiene el id del conductor, y el conductor no tiene el id del telefono, no necesitas una tabla intermedia.. como lo mostras no esta bien.. y de la otra forma no es necesario...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que estás trabajando con PDO, la misma tiene un método que se encargará de obtener el valor deseado, es decir **`lastInsertId()`**

Para usarlo, deberás:

- Ejecutar la query de inserción
- Idealmente declarar una variable donde asignes la variable de conexión y el acceso de esta al método antes mencionado
- Si haces un echo de dicha variable encontrarás el id del último registro almacenado

Código

```
$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tubase", "root", "contrasenia");

$newChof = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO tabla(columna1, columna2)
                                VALUES('valor1', 'valor2')");

$newChof->execute();

$ultimoRegistro = $conexion->lastInsertId();
```

**Fuente consultada**

- [Ejemplo PDO de lastInsertId()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.lastinsertid.php#85129)
- [PDO lastInsertId()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Comment: He intentado hacer lo que me comentabas con el método, pero siempre me devuelve 0, ¿A caso es por cómo están nombrados mis ID's en la tabla?. Actualizo la pregunta con la definición de estas.

Comment: Ya vi la solución, aunque no entiendo muy bien el por qué. Guardé `Conexion::Conectar();`  en una variable `$PDO` antes de ejecutar la consulta como me explicabas, pero no sé porque solo arroja los ID correctamente cuando viene de la variable y no directamente. Y para obtener el ID basto con usarla de la siguiente forma `$conductorID = $PDO->lastInsertId(); ` y ya arroja los ID correspondientes. Fue de muchísima ayuda tu respuesta. Gracias.

Comment: Se estaria ejecutando sobre otra transaccion? esto me da miedo sin que este todo en una transaccion...

Comment: `lastInsertId()` devuelve el último id insertado usando _conexión_ actual. Si cambias de conexión, lógicamente el resultado es diferente.

Comment: @Triby ¿Entonces al hacerlo directamente estoy abriendo una nueva conexión que no esta ejecutando nada y por eso siempre me devuelve el cero?

Comment: Parece que `Conexion::Conectar()` siempre crea una nueva conexión y por eso no funcionaba hasta que la guardaste en una variable.